# PHP: how to remove by regular expression from a precise characther to the end of the string

Tags: php, arrays, expression, str-replace

I have an array like this below:

```
Array("string|||mfasdfhadskjfahsldfhcadkasldhfaf", "apple|||2345hrquwfiqfh4fhlqwu4f", "orange|||0erjoerhtqothcro")
```

What I would like to achieve is:

```
Array("string", "apple", "orange")
```

What regular expression I can use to remove all the characters after the "|||"?

Kind regards,
Massi

Comment: We would love to see your coding attempt.

Comment: You can use https://regex101.com/ to understand what's going on with a regex while you're trying to write a proper one

Answer (score 2):

In your simple case it's enough to use `strstr` function:

```
$arr = ["string|||mfasdfhadskjfahsldfhcadkasldhfaf", "apple|||2345hrquwfiqfh4fhlqwu4f", "orange|||0erjoerhtqothcro"];

$result = array_map(function ($s) {
    return strstr($s, '|||', true);
}, $arr);

print_r($result);
```

The output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => string
    [1] => apple
    [2] => orange
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `array_map` in combination with a simple `preg_replace` call.

You just have to replace everything after the first `|` with `''`.

```
$data = ...
$data = array_map(function($item) {
    return preg_replace('~\|.*$~', '', $item);
}, $data);
```

If you need exactly 3 times the pipe char, just use `\|{3}.*$`

Answer (score 1):

Here are two ways, I recommend the second because it doesn't use regex.

However, the nice thing about `preg_replace()` is that you don't need to write a loop.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/toe5e))

```
$array = ["string|||mfasdfhadskjfahsldfhcadkasldhfaf", "apple|||2345hrquwfiqfh4fhlqwu4f", "orange|||0erjoerhtqothcro"];
var_export(preg_replace('~\|.*~', '', $array));

echo "\n----\n";

foreach ($array as &$value) {  // modify by reference to overwrite the input array 
    $value = strstr($value, '|', true);
}
var_export($array);
```

Output:

```
array (
  0 => 'string',
  1 => 'apple',
  2 => 'orange',
)
----
array (
  0 => 'string',
  1 => 'apple',
  2 => 'orange',
)
```

Or `strstr()` without modifying by reference, you could declare a new result array like this:

```
foreach ($array as $value) {
    $result[] = strstr($value, '|', true);
}
```

p.s. Of course if your real data requires three consecutive pipes, you can extend my *needle* character two more times.